# pymongo.MongoClient did not connect on making instance

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I keep seeing examples of using MongoClient like this (simplified):

```
import pymongo

try:
   conn=pymongo.MongoClient(‘localhost’,27017)
   print('connected')
except:
   print('not connected')
```

But there is no connection, because when I do this

```
import pymongo
print(pymongo.MongoClient('blabla'))
```

I get:

```
MongoClient(host=['blabla:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
```

The actual connection is going on when I call for example `.find()`.

This seem very weird and confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

> Note Starting with version 3.0 the MongoClient constructor no longer blocks while connecting to the server or servers, and it no longer raises ConnectionFailure if they are unavailable, nor ConfigurationError if the user’s credentials are wrong. Instead, the constructor returns immediately and launches the connection process on background threads. You can check if the server is available like this: